# IndexError, except doesnt work. Django

Tags: django, view, try-catch

In `views` I have:

```
        def cars(request, cars_id):
            try:
                 car = Car.objects.filter(id=cars_id).values('model')
                 all_cars = Models.objects.filter(cars_id=cars_id).values('id', 
                 'name', 'cars_id')
            except Car.DoesNotExist:
                 cars_id=1
            except Exception, e:
                 print e
            except IndexError:
                 cars_id=1
            return render_to_response('cars.html', {'all_cars': all_cars, 'car':car[0]['model']})
```

So, in browser I enter, for example, *car/10000000/*, and I have an error:

**IndexError: list index out of range**.

Why my 'except' doesnt work and how to fix it?

Comment: This code snippet won't raise the execption you are trying to catch; so the error is somewhere else.

Comment: can you post whole traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the last line `car[0]['model']`. When you don't have a car with the specified `cars_id`, the `car` list is empty, so you get an `IndexError`. The fix is to get a default car when the car requested doesn't exist - the default car is `id = 1`.

However, your `all_cars` is the same as your `car` line, except it contains extra fields. In other words, `all_cars` will have one car or zero cars when `cars_id` is invalid.

So its better to have `all_cars` be a listing of all cars in your database:

```
def cars(request, cars_id):
    all_cars = Models.objects.all().values('id',
               'name', 'cars_id')
    car = Car.objects.filter(id=cars_id).values('model')
    if not car:
        car = Car.objects.filter(id=1).values('model')
    return render_to_response('cars.html', {'all_cars': all_cars,
                                            'car':car[0]['model']})
```

Comment: filter() never raises DoesNotExist

Comment: Right you are @yedpodtrzitko - fixed.

Comment: Also, you can not apply `car[0]` for `car` returned by `get` method and you can not apply `values()` to it.

Comment: In case of there is no `Car` with `id=1` (quite likely) `IndexError` will be thrown. Sorry for criticism

Answer (score 2):

If you want to catch object existence, I recomend you to use [DoesNotExist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.DoesNotExist) exception

```
def cars(request, cars_id):
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(id=cars_id).values('model')
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        #other stuff
```

According to your updated question: you are trying to get first item of `None`. You should get car model for return in your try/except statement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your IndexError is thrown at an other location. For testing purposes try to wrap your entire view in a generic try catch block.

```
try:
    car = Car.objects.filter(id=cars_id).values('model')
    #include here all the other stuff you are doing
except Exception, e
     print e
```

Your view - rewrote:

```
def cars(request, cars_id):
        #to see whether you passed cars_id correctly
        print "cars_id is"
        print cars_id
        all_cars = Models.objects.filter(cars_id=cars_id).values('id', 
             'name', 'cars_id')
        try:
             car = Car.objects.get(id=cars_id).values('model') 
        except Car.DoesNotExist:
             print "the car for the given ID does not exist
        #just return the "entire" car object in the context of the response.
        #in the template you can then access car.model
        return render_to_response('cars.html', {'all_cars': all_cars, 'car':car})
```

Comment: Not a good idea. `try/except` should be succint and explicit.

Comment: tim your view is full of things you should not do. I will try to rewrite it for you.

Answer (score 0):

1) learn about Exceptions hiearchy: If there's `except` block of Exception first and IndexError later, IndexError is never catched, because it's child class of Exception (see 
http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy)

2) `filter()` never raises `DoesNotExist` exception, you have to check if there's some record in obtained `QuerySet`.

3) your problem is zero index in `return` line.

4) code should possibly looks like this:

```
def cars(request, cars_id):
    try:
        car = Car.objects.get(id=cars_id)
    except Car.DoesNotExist:
        #anyway - are you sure Car w/ id always exists?
        car = Car.objects.all()[:1] #get first car

    all_cars = Models.objects.filter(cars_id=cars_id).values('id', 'name', 'cars_id')
    return render_to_response('cars.html', {'all_cars': all_cars, 'car':car.model})
```

Comment: **'Car' object has no attribute 'values'** - if I use `car = Car.objects.get(id=cars_id).values('model')`.

Comment: **'Car' object has no attribute '__getitem__'** in return

Comment: with `'car':car.model` works, but if I use `car/10000000/` - **'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name'** (AttributeError)

Comment: provide more data from your traceback, pls